# How to use a variable inside Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this line in my loop:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp('' + myClass + '[:*].*');
var rule1 = string.match(regex1)
```

Where "string" is a string of class selectors, for example: `.hb-border-top:before, .hb-border-left`

and "myClass" is a class: `.hb-border-top`

As I cycle through strings, i need to match strings that have "myClass" in them, including :before and :hover but not including things like `hb-border-top2`.

My idea for this regex is to match `hb-border-top` and then `:*` to match none or more colons and then the rest of the string.

I need to match:

`.hb-fill-top::before
.hb-fill-top:hover::before
.hb-fill-top
.hb-fill-top:hover`

but the above returns only:

`.hb-fill-top::before
.hb-fill-top:hover::before
.hb-fill-top:hover`

and doesn't return `.hb-fill-top` itself.

So, it has to match `.hb-fill-top` itself and then anything that follows as long as it starts with `:`

**EDIT:**

Picture below: my strings are the contents of {selectorText}.
A string is either a single class or a class with a pseudo element, or a rule with few clases in it, divided by commas.

each string that contains `.hb-fill-top` **ONLY** or `.hb-fill-top:` + something (hover, after, etc) has to be selected. Class is gonna be in variable "myClass" hence my issue as I can't be too precise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to get any CSS selector name that *contains* the value anywhere inside and has EITHER `:` and 0+ chars up to the end of string OR finish right there.

Then, to get matches for the `.hb-fill-top` value you need a solution like

```
/\.hb-fill-top(?::.*)?$/
```

and the following JS code to make it all work:

```js
var key = ".hb-fill-top";
var rx = RegExp(key.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?::.*)?$");
var ss = ["something.hb-fill-top::before","something2.hb-fill-top:hover::before","something3.hb-fill-top",".hb-fill-top:hover",".hb-fill-top2:hover",".hb-fill-top-2:hover",".hb-fill-top-bg-br"];
var res = ss.filter(x => rx.test(x));
console.log(res);
```

Note that `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` code is necessary to escape the `.` that is a special regex metacharacter that matches any char but a line break char. See [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/3832970).

The `^` matches the start of a string.

`(?::.*)?$` will match:

- `(?::.*)?$` - an optional (due to the last `?` quantifier that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified subpattern) sequence (`(?:...)?` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon)) of a

  - `:` - a colon
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of the string.

Comment: I will check it when I'm back from work, thanks for the answer. As you can see in the edited question, I have a list of strings that I have to select. String is either 1 (selected) or 0 (skipped) based on this regex. So if the string matches the "key" or "key" with hover, after elements etc, then it will be selected.
I'm building a function which basically takes my whole stylesheet, cycles through all the rules and returns only the rules that apply to the class I have put in the "key". It has to return all :hover, :before rules and other chained rules that include "key" in some way.

Comment: When you use `^` to mark start of the string here : `RegExp("^" + key.replace ....` does this not mean that string will only match if it starts with "key" ? Will it work if "key" is somewhere in the middle of the string?

Comment: @Varin: The `^` anchors the match at the start of the string. Remove if you do not need that behavior. I edited the JS snippet to `filter` out the non-matching values.

Comment: I downloaded my git repo at work, pasted your regex and it works! It works without the replace string which I don't think I need in this case...

also, could you please explain `(?::.*)?$` in bit more detail, especially the `?$` part? I'm trying to understand regex more and this would really help! Thanks so much for your help Wiktor!

Comment: @Varin I  added some more explanations.

Comment: Thanks. This is clear to me now. One more thing, the replace string is there to escape the dots inside the "key"? I thought that if you pass a variable inside RegExp, the special characters are already escaped, no?

Comment: @Varin That is not the case in any language. In Ruby, you can pass an array to `Regexp.union` that will create an alternation pattern with `|` operators while escaping each value. And that is the only auto-escaping method I know.

Comment: It works in my code but for some reason doesn't in the regex tester... weird:
https://regex101.com/r/rj8XZR/2

Comment: @Varin You are testing against a multiline string. `$` matches at the end of string by default in PCRE/JS/.NET.... anywhere but Ruby and text editors. So, you need to add `m` *MULTILINE* modifier. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rj8XZR/3). Mind you need to escape the dot.

Comment: I see, I'll remember about the flags. Thank you for taking time to educate me! I have a lot to learn when it comes to regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex1 = new RegExp('\\' + myClass + '(?::[^\s]*)?');
var rule1 = string.match(regex1)
```

This regex select my class, and everething after if it start with `:` and stop when it meets a whitespace character.

[See the regex in action.](https://regex101.com/r/rj8XZR/1)

Notice also that I added `'\\'` at the beginning. This is in order to escape the dot in your className. Otherwise it would have matched something else like

```
ahb-fill-top
.some-other-hb-fill-top
```

Also be careful about `.*` it may match something else after (I don't know your set of strings). You might want to be more precise with `:{1,2}[\w-()]+` in the last group. So:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp('\\' + myClass + '(?::{1,2}[\w-()]+)?');
```

Comment: This also returns things like: `.hb-fill-top-rev-bg` and doesn't select the rest of the string that follows after `.hb-fill-top:`

Comment: Yes it does, see my last edit :) Be sure to detail more your question: for instance add regex that you **don't** want to match. Then our answers will be more appropriate for sure.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns error in the console : `Range out of order in character class`

Comment: Doesn't for me.. I'll need more context if you want I to help you

Comment: I edited my question with a picture of a few strings and a further explanation

Comment: Basically, needs to select every string that has:  `class`, `.class:hover`, `.class::hover`, `.class:after`, `.class:hover::after` etc.  and all we have is a variable with `class`. All it has to do in order to work for me, is to be able to select strings that have `class` on their own as well as `class:` (and the rest of the string that follows after `:`) but not `class-2` or `class2` etc.

Comment: Sorry I left yesterday, but here is the new regex.

Answer (score 0):

`` var regex1 = new RegExp(`^\\${myClass}(:{1,2}\\w+)*$`) ``

```js
var passes = [
    '.hb-fill-top::before',
    '.hb-fill-top:hover::before',
    '.hb-fill-top',
    '.hb-fill-top:hover',
    '.hb-fill-top::before',
    '.hb-fill-top:hover::before',
    '.hb-fill-top:hover'
];

var fails = ['.hb-fill-top-bg-br'];

var myClass = '.hb-fill-top';
var regex = new RegExp(`^\\${myClass}(:{1,2}\\w+)*$`);

passes.forEach(p => console.log(regex.test(p)));
console.log('---');
fails.forEach(f => console.log(regex.test(f)));
```

Comment: Returns things like `.hb-fill-top-bg-br` and it should only return `hb-fill-top` and `hb-fill-top:[rest of the string]`

Comment: Updated. That string now fails and the 7 in your post pass. Can you try again?